# Python How to get the each letters put into a word?

Tags: python

When the name is given, for example `Aberdeen Scotland`.

I need to get the result of `Adbnearldteoecns`.

Leaving the first word plain, but reverse the last word and put in between the first word.

I have done so far:

```
coordinatesf = "Aberdeen Scotland"

for line in coordinatesf:
    separate =  line.split()
    for i in separate [0:-1]:
        lastw = separate[1][::-1]
        print(i)
```

Comment: Stopping tagging your algorithm questions with the editor you use.

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty but it works:

```
coordinatesf = "Aberdeen Scotland"
new_word=[]
#split the two words

words = coordinatesf.split(" ")

#reverse the second and put to lowercase

words[1]=words[1][::-1].lower()

#populate the new string

for index in range(0,len(words[0])):
    new_word.insert(2*index,words[0][index])
for index in range(0,len(words[1])):
    new_word.insert(2*index+1,words[1][index])
outstring = ''.join(new_word)
print outstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you want to do is only well-defined if the the input string is composed of two words with the same lengths.
I use assertions to make sure that is true but you can leave them out.

```
def scramble(s):
    words = s.split(" ")
    assert len(words) == 2
    assert len(words[0]) == len(words[1])
    scrambledLetters = zip(words[0], reversed(words[1]))
    return "".join(x[0] + x[1] for x in scrambledLetters)

>>> print(scramble("Aberdeen Scotland"))
>>> AdbnearldteoecnS
```

You could replace the x[0] + x[1] part with sum() but I think that makes it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

This splits the input, zips the first word with the reversed second word, joins the pairs, then joins the list of pairs.

```python
coordinatesf = "Aberdeen Scotland"  
a,b = coordinatesf.split()
print(''.join(map(''.join, zip(a,b[::-1]))))
```